# How to use plist in iOS native application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I want to use plist file in our iOS application. As I gone through some articles but i could not collect required info. Please help me on this.

Comment: What is the purpose for using plist ?

Comment: This question is incredibly vague. You don't say what you want to use plists for, you don't say anything in particular about the troubles you are having.

Comment: @dreamlax how it is unclear. I just ask that I want to use plist then obvious I want to store some keys that I want to use throughout the application. hence I just want to know the way how it's doing?

Comment: @iMash: You haven't said specifically what part about plists you are having a problem with. What you've said is "I want to drive a car. I've read some articles but I could not collect required info. Please help me on this". How can anyone help you if they don't know what part you need help with? If you need help with all of it, then your question is too vague anyway. You don't even say what articles you've read.

Answer (score 1):

you can use in this way:-

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dataList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

this array can be used to populate tableview or any other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about reading and writing data from property lists, the relevant documentation is the [Property List Programming Guide].(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW3)

This extract should help you:

## Using Core Foundation Functions to Read and Write Property-List Data

> You have two major ways to write property-list data to the file system:
>
> If the root object of the property list is an NSDictionary or NSArray object—which is almost always the case—you can invoke the writeToFile:atomically: or writeToURL:atomically: methods of those classes, passing in the root object. These methods save the graph of property-list objects as an XML property list before writing that out as a file or URL resource.
>   To read the property-list data back into your program, initialize an allocated collection object by calling the initWithContentsOfFile: and initWithContentsOfURL: methods or the corresponding class factory methods (for example, dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:).
>
> To expand on this last point, consider this example. You have an XML property list whose root object is an NSArray object containing a number of NSDictionary objects. If you load that property list with this call:

`NSArray * a = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:xmlFile];`

> a is an immutable array with immutable dictionaries in each element. Each key and each value in each dictionary are also immutable.
>
> If you load the property list with this call:

`NSMutableArray * ma = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:xmlFile];`

> ma is a mutable array with immutable dictionaries in each element. Each key and each value in each dictionary are immutable.
>
> If you need finer-grained control over the mutability of the objects in a property list, use the propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription: class method, whose second parameter permits you to specify the mutability of objects at various levels of the aggregate property list. You could specify that all objects are immutable (NSPropertyListImmutable), that only the container (array and dictionary) objects are mutable (NSPropertyListMutableContainers), or that all objects are mutable (NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves).
>
> For example, you could write code like this:

`NSMutableArray *dma = (NSMutableArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                        propertyListFromData:plistData
                        mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                        format:&format
                        errorDescription:&error];`

> This call produces a mutable array with mutable dictionaries in each element. Each key and each value in each dictionary are themselves also mutable.

Answer (score 0):

It Very simple to get data form `plist` such like,

```
self.YorArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourplistName" ofType:@"plist"]];
```